# removing RequireJS from Typescript visual studio template

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, requirejs, typescript, nuget

I've recently installed RequireJS into my Typescript template via nuget package manager. But then decided to uninstall it again because it's overkill for what I want. I went back into nuget and uninstalled the package. The file were removed correctly. But my Typescript is still compiling with requireJS functions which now are undefined functions when running. How can I fix this so it compiles back without the requireJS functions?

I tried closing and reopening the solution, removing the .js files and recompiling, changing some code but to no avail.

Generated JS:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) { /* my code */ }
```

Comment: Can you share your typescript file? It looks like your TS file is an external module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just copied over the files into a new Project.